# JFrame cannot be resolved to a type or variable

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

I can't run my code because of this error which says: "JFrame cannot be resolved to a type.
    JFrame cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
package figurat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setTitle("Audi");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(500,500);
     grafiku f1= new grafiku();
      frame.add(f1);
      frame.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: at ushtrime/figurat.test.main(test.java:8)

Comment: what is `grafiku`?

Comment: Can you provide the complete stacktrace? and on which line it happens. Here in SO there are no lines visible.

Comment: Please share the Java version you are using and, especially if you are using Java 9 or later, if your module-info contains ```requires java.desktop;```.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 JFrame cannot be resolved to a type
 JFrame cannot be resolved to a type
 JFrame cannot be resolved to a variable

 at ushtrime/figurat.test.main(test.java:8)

Comment: Just maybe a dumb question. Did you save the file? Because at least in your question, there is no code on line 8.

Comment: line 8 is : JFrame frame = new JFrame();

Comment: I saved the file

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get “grafiku cannot be resolved to a type”. When I comment out that line and the following one, your code runs nicely and opens a window.